# How to paginate search results in Django?

Tags: python, django, pagination

The code below searches for the word in dictionary, and render results on *search.html*, so I need to paginate results on that page, how can I do that? I read the arcticle here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/, but I have no idea how to embed the pagination code to mine.

```
def search(request):
    if 'results' in request.GET and request.GET['results']:
        results = request.GET['results']
        word = words.objects.filter(title__icontains = results).order_by('title')
        return render_to_response('myapp/search.html',
        {'word': word, 'query': results })
    else:
        return render(request, 'myapp/search.html')
```

Comment: What did you try? The docs has an example to use the [paginator in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view. That example is paginating a queryset  `contact_list`, you just need to paginate your queryset `word` instead.

Comment: As an aside, your code would be less confusing if you named your model `Word` (capitalised, singular), named your queryset `words` (there can be more than one result), and used `render` everywhere instead of `render_to_response`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm new in Python/Django, and I still have much to learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def search(request):
    if 'results' in request.GET and request.GET['results']:
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        results = request.GET['results']
        word = words.objects.filter(title__icontains = results).order_by('title')
        paginator = Paginator(word, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page
        word = paginator.page(page)
        return render_to_response('myapp/search.html',
                 {'word': word, 'query': results })
    else:
        return render(request, 'myapp/search.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using the ListView  Class when i need pagination on a queried data, and overiding the query_set function. Something like this...

```
class FoodMenuView(generic.ListView):
    paginate_by = 10 #use your paginated  value here
    template_name = 'order/_food_menu.html' # your own template
    context_object_name = "list_of_food"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Food.objects.filter(price=request.GET['price'])
```

Comment: as much as i like CBV, that doesn't work for me.
I also use `itertools` and merge results from several requests via `queryset = sorted(chain(...))`

Comment: We need to use `self.request` to access the variable `request` in `get_queryset` method.