# Pagination for Django search results

Tags: python, django, search

I want to add **pagination** to my search results in `django`. This is my search function form `views.py` for the relevant (Jobs) module:

```
def search(request):

    queryset_list = Job.objects.order_by('-publishing_date')
    if 'keywords'in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)

    if 'state' in request.GET:
        state = request.GET['state']
        if state:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(location__iexact=state)
            
    if 'job_type' in request.GET:
        job_type = request.GET['job_type']
        if job_type:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(job_type__iexact=job_type_choices)
    if 'industry' in request.GET:
        industry = request.GET['industry']
        if industry:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(industry__icontains=industry_choices)

    if 'salary' in request.GET:
        salary = request.GET['salary']
        if salary:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(salary__lte=salary)
            
    context = {
        'location_choices':location_choices,
        'salary_choices':salary_choices,
        'job_type_choices':job_type_choices,
        'industry_choices':industry_choices,
        'jobs':queryset_list,
        'values':request.GET,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'jobs/search.html', context)
```

This is pagination function from the same file:

```
def index(request):

    jobs = Job.objects.order_by('-publishing_date').filter(is_published=True)
    
    paginator = Paginator(jobs, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_jobs = paginator.get_page(page)
    
    context = {
        'jobs': paged_jobs
    }  
    
    return render(request, 'jobs/jobs.html', context)
```

Both of them work (search returns results and pagination works on listing page) however I want to have pagination too for my search results. I am very new to python and django, and assume there is more elegant way of writing my search function, so please do not hesitate to let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You can do the same as you did in index view, passing the queryset_list instead of jobs. paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 6)
page = request.GET.get('page')
paged_jobs = paginator.get_page(page)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried adding that to search function, but it did not work.  I am confused how I can make sure that the search results are filtered based on all the entered search criteria and are paginated if there are more than 6 of those results

Comment: What happens when you add paging? Is there an error, or it doesn’t page the result?

Comment: Nothing, no error but also no pagination for search results

Comment: Maybe I am adding that in a wrong place?

Comment: You should add just above context = {...}. And pass 'jobs': paged_jobs in the context dict.

Comment: I have two dictionary 'jobs' items in the same context then.  'jobs':queryset_list, &   'jobs':paged_jobs

Comment: I was looking online and thinking perhaps I need to rewrite my search function and use this method? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724208/how-to-paginate-search-results-in-django